# Number of Sigma Bonds in this Structure Containing a Ring

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, covalent-compounds

(This question was on my last gen. chemistry exam.)

I counted 12 sigma bonds, but the answer was 13. I'm taking this course online so there is no explanation given. Could anyone offer a quick explanation on how this structure could give 13 sigma bonds?

> [image]

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you have any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: You might also want to give the site's [homework policy](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) a read. In this particular post, simply counting the number of bonds would suffice as "effort" IMHO (I don't see what more could be done). Do bear in mind though, that homework-type questions (posted without any effort taken towards solving it) tend to get closed. Welcome to Chemistry.SE, cheers! :-)

Comment: The simple answer is that all bonds (in this molecule) contain $\sigma$ orbitals but a few also contain $\pi$ orbitals!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There're are 13 sigma bonds there (count the red lines),

[image]

---

You've clearly tried to attempt this yourself, so good on you (and by virtue of that, it's equally clear that you counted the bonds too hastily).

I counted (quickly, because it looked simple enough) and got 12 too at first. Counted a little slower the second time (I was actually going to attempt to prove to you that the number of bonds *is* 12), turns out the ring is not entirely conjugated, so one carbon atom in it actually has *two* hydrogen atoms bonded to it. ;-)